# All that [gold] is not gold

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, meta, burninate-request

I’ll make it short: Please delete the [gold](/questions/tagged/gold) tag as it is pointless. There are one or two questions that are actually **about** gold badges in general without being about specific badges, but I cannot imagine how anybody would use this tag for searching or any other useful purpose.